# How to import from subdirectory from a node_module?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, history.js, create-react-app

I'm using `create-react-app` and I have a line that says:

```
import createHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
```

but this doesn't work and it throws an error:

```
Error in ./src/deps/history.js.
Module not found: 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory' 
in /home/aurimus/Apps/projects/my-project/src/deps
```

Is this specifically not supported by `create-react-app`? How do I circumvent this?

******UPDATE******

After correction to the url of the lib (was using an outdated tutorial), I still get nothing imported, `createBrowserHistory` is `undefined`

I'm using additional file to abstract the `import`:

Inside *deps/history.js*

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory.js'
export default createBrowserHistory
```

Inside *index.js*

```
import history from './deps/history';
history.listen(render); // history is undefined
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this specifically not supported by create-react-app?

No, this has nothing to do with `create-react-app`.

> How do I circumvent this?

The error tells you exactly what the problem is:

> Module not found: 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

That means `history/lib/createBrowserHistory` doesn't exist, i.e. you are using the wrong path.

I installed `history`, looked at the package contents and noticed that the file `createBrowserHistory` is located in the root of the package (in fact, there is no `lib/` directory). That means you want to import `history/createBrowserHistory`.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the not found thing, but now it's still undefined after import. Any suggestions? Updated the question

Comment: @Aurimas: Look at the file and check what it exports and how. `history` shouldn't be `undefined`, but `history.listen` probably is. The file exports a function, not an object. The function returns an object with a `listen` property, so you need to call the function first. If you don't know what value(s) a module is exporting, look at its source.

Comment: If you could say anything in following problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356481/how-to-get-the-last-key-of-object-which-has-a-value/42356657

Answer (score 1):

From [history docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#installation):

```
Using npm:

$ npm install --save history
Then with a module bundler like webpack, use as you would anything else:

// using ES6 modules
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

// using CommonJS modules
var createHistory = require('history').createBrowserHistory
```

Answer (score 0):

My final solution that worked is thanks to Felix:

In `deps/history.js`

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory.js'
export default createBrowserHistory()
```

Then in `index.js`

```
import history from './deps/history';
...
...
history.listen(render);
```